# Проблемы при создании Notification icons

Tags: android, icon, android-notification

Имеется png-картинка, из неё пытаюсь сделать иконки для отображения нотификаций. Попробовал два варианта:

1) Через студию, правой кнопкой по ресурсам->new->new image asset
2) И вариант на этом [сайте](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html). По сути, одно и тоже.

В обоих случаях вот [такой](http://joxi.ru/52aQ948Ieexy20) результат, т.е. абсолютно пустые иконки, хотя родительское изображение отображает лого. Сталкивался кто с таким?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно гайдлайнам, значки уведомлений должны представлять собой изображение белого цвета на прозрачном фоне: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/design/patterns/notifications.html

> Правильно
>
> Стремитесь к визуальной простоте значков, избегайте излишних
> трудноразличимых деталей.
>
> Неправильно
>
> Чтобы ваше приложение отличалось от других, используйте цвет.

Да, не особо приятно. Но и рассматривать мелкие цветные детали на мелких иконочках тоже не особо приятно, так что, с одной стороны, сделали даже правильно.

Comment: Это помогло. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Нет, такого не бывало, но я имею представление из-за чего это. Как 1, так и 2 вариант, при создании иконки для уведомлений используется фильтр, для рендеринга, учитывая пожелания от google. Как и написано выше - белый цвет.

Всё что происходит по сути, ваш png полностью перекрашивается этим фильтром, а это значит проблема в самой png. Существуют несколько классных уроков на оф сайте devbytes, как подготавливать icon, для дальнейшего применения.

Что касается причины этого, на мой взгляд два очевидных варианта: Ваша png не имеет прозрачного фона или alpha-канал слабо выражен (имеет тень, или заливку). По сути он и перекрашивает вашу иконку.

Comment: Да, примерно так. Всё что не имело прозрачность, замазывалось белым слоем и все.